# Can anyone help me install Tp Link TL-WN722N?

Tags: networking, drivers, tp-link

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, I followed all the instructions [here](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201812/20181207/Installation%20Guide%20for%20Linux.pdf) but I just keep having error when perform

```
sudo make clean
```

and

```
sudo make
```

it gives me error 2:

```
    $ sudo make
    make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/build 
    M=/home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/osdep_service.h:46,
                 from /home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/osdep_service_linux.h:288:8: error: ‘_timer’ {aka ‘struct timer_list’} has no member named ‘data’
  288 |  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
      |        ^~
/home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/osdep_service_linux.h:289:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  289 |  init_timer(ptimer);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~
      |  _init_timer
In file included from /home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/drv_types.h:35,
                 from /home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/wifi.h: At top level:
/home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/wifi.h:1012: warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined
 1012 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40
      | 
In file included from /home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/osdep_service_linux.h:86,
                 from /home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/osdep_service.h:46,
                 from /home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
./include/linux/ieee80211.h:1451: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 1451 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF  0x100
      | 
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1719: /home/ronan/Downloads/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1911: modules] Error 2
```

Thank you all for your precious times!

PS: out put of `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy 
series, misc. (MTP mode)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 09da:2403 A4Tech Co., Ltd. 2.4G Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:9271 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
AR9271 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Was the dongle connected when you ran this command?

Comment: You are installing a wrong driver.

Comment: Firstly Thank you for your fast reply
Secondly i want to apologise if my question is so dead simple or stupid since I’m a complete beginner. 
And i ran the installation with the dongle connected. I was sure I installed the correct driver for TL-WN722N. Let me have another check. Thank you!

Comment: Please post `lsusb` with the TL-WN722N connected.

Comment: After a quick search. My Wifi is listed as Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
AR9271 802.11n (as shown above) and yes, I installed the wrong driver. Does it mean it doesn't need any additional driver?
Thank you!

Comment: This device `0cf3:9271` is supported by the 5.4 linux kernel. No drivers are needed. Does it work?

Comment: See https://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-focal.git/tree/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/hif_usb.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The

```
0cf3:9271 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR9271 802.11n device
```

is natively supported by the 5.4 Linux kernel and doesn't need any drivers.

See https://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-focal.git/tree/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/hif_usb.c

You were trying to install a driver for a completely different `RTL8188EUS` device. Also that driver is obsolete anyway as you can see at the top of the manual. It is for Ubuntu 16.04 with the 4.13 kernel.

It won't install to 20.04 either way.

Comment: That seemed to help! V1 of TL-WN722N doesn't need additional driver!

Answer (score 0):

I have ubuntu 20.04 on a HP Laptop model 15-dy2050la

I connected the TP-LINK TLWN722N to the laptop, ubuntu recognized it, but could not connect to the internet.
My router worked perfectly, I have other devices that connected without problem
When executing the command;
lsusb
Ubuntu recognized the TP-LINK TLWN722N:
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 2357:010c TP-Link TL-WN722N v2
Ubuntu recognized the device without installing or compiling anything.
But it didn't connect to the internet

My wifi was set to be hidden.
I disabled the option to hide my wifi:
Broadcast Network Name (SSID)
And by magic the TP-LINK TLWN722N connected to the wifi
Ubuntu recognized the device without installing or compiling anything.

Now I can choose between using the internal modem or the TP-LINK TLWN722N
The HP Laptop model 15-dy2050la is very cheap...  the modem it comes with is not as powerful or stable, that's why I use the TP-LINK TLWN722N

With the internal modem of the HP Laptop model 15-dy2050la I struggled with streaming, online games and video conferences, but thanks to the TP-LINK TLWN722N that was in the past